# GET http://localhost:8888/appraisal/appraisal_goals/findScore?id=2 404 (Not Found) in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have been battling with this Laravel-5.8 code for some hours now:

```
CREATE TABLE `appraisal_goal_types` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `max_score` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The table diagram:
[image: table diagram]

```
CREATE TABLE `appraisal_goals` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `goal_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

From the table, if parent_id is null then the row is a parent. Each child field will have its parent_id. The parent can have many child rows. Also, Only the parent can have value for max_score. The child will have 0 as its default for max_score

In my view blade I have a dropdown that will only be populated with the child fields.

I have written this function in my Controller

```
public function findScore(Request $request)
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $child  = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->find($request->id) or abort(404);
    $maxscore = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->select('max_score')->find($child->parent_id);
    return response()->json($maxscore);
}

public function create()
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;

    $identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id','appraisal_name')->where('company_id', 
$userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first();

  $goaltypes   =       AppraisalGoalType::where('company_id', $userCompany)->get(); 
 $categories = AppraisalGoalType::with('children')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->whereNull('parent_id')->get();

return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.create')
        ->with('goaltypes', $goaltypes)
        ->with('categories', $categories)
        ->with('identities', $identities)
        ;
}
```

Model

```
class AppraisalGoalType extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'appraisal_goal_types';
  protected $primaryKey = 'id';

  protected $fillable = [
          'name',
          'company_id',
          'parent_id',
          'max_score',
      ];

  protected $casts = [];

  public function children()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Appraisal\AppraisalGoalType', 'parent_id');
  }

  public function parent()
  {
      return $this->hasOne(App\Models\Appraisal\AppraisalGoalType::class, 'id', 'parent_id');
  }  
}
```

I am sending the max_score as json.

route/web.php

Route::get('/appraisal/appraisal_goals/findScore','Appraisal\AppraisalGoalsController@findScore');

create.blade.php

```html
  <form  action="{{route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.store')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {{csrf_field()}}
   
   <div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-body">
    <div class="row">
        
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label"> Goal Type:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
          <select id="goal_type" class="form-control" name="goal_type_id">
            <option value="">Select Goal Type</option>

            @foreach ($categories as $category)
            @unless($category->name === 'Job Fundamentals')
              <option hidden value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ $category->id == old('category_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>

              @if ($category->children)
                @foreach ($category->children as $child)
                @unless($child->name === 'Job Fundamentals')
                  <option value="{{ $child->id }}" {{ $child->id == old('category_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $child->name }}</option>
                @endunless
                @endforeach
              @endif
              @endunless
            @endforeach
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>    

<input type="text" id="max_score" class="form-control" >

</form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('change', '#goal_type', function() {
            var air_id =  $(this).val();

            var a = $(this).parent();

            console.log("Its Change !");

            var op = "";

            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: 'findScore',
                data: { 'id': air_id },
                dataType: 'json',      //return data will be json
                success: function(data) {
                    // console.log("price");
                    console.log(data.max_score);

                    a.find('#max_score').val(data.max_score); 
                    // do you want to display id or registration name?
                },
                error:function(){

                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Expand snippet

The child does not have value for max_score, but the parent has. When a child field is selected, I want to load the max_score of its parent.

The findScore function in the controller is to select the max_score of the parent of a requested id of the child.

However, when I click on the dropdown to load the max_score of the parent with the related goal_type_id, I got this error in the console:

> GET http://localhost:8888/peopleedge/appraisal/appraisal_goals/findScore?id=2 404 (Not Found)

How do I resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: had answered your same question yesterday. you are using wrong url in ajax. give a name to your url and then use the named route in your ajax request.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon - The error is still there. I even tried to rewrite the entire code all over again.

Comment: do you use a named route?? or use the full path instead of just `findScore`

Comment: @zahidhasanemon -  Route:  See it here:    Route::get('/appraisal/appraisal_goals/findScore','Appraisal\AppraisalGoalsController@findScore');

Comment: @zahidhasanemon - I am still having this error:  http://localhost:8888/peopleedge/appraisal/appraisal_goals/findScore?goal_type_id=2   page not found error 404

Comment: because you dont have a url like that. your url is `appraisal/appraisal_goals/findScore` not `peopleedge/appraisal/appraisal_goals/findScore`

Comment: `url: '{{ url( 'appraisal/appraisal_goals/findScore' ) }}'` change url in ajax request like this.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon - How do I get over this?

Comment: @zahidhasanemon - I added url: '{{ url( 'appraisal/appraisal_goals/findScore' ) }}', but the same error still exists

Comment: adding an answer. check that out.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon - which answer do I check out?

Answer (score 0):

route

```
Route::get('appraisal/appraisal_goals/findScore','Appraisal\AppraisalGoalsController@findScore')->name('findScore');
```

and the ajax url

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'get',
   url: '{{ route('findScore') }}',
   ......
```

Comment: Problem still there

Comment: still getting 404 ??